# Configure flake8 to use a plugin from the local repository

Tags: flake8

I am trying to add my own flake8 plugin that lives in the same repository as the code I want to check, and follow the [official documentation](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/configuration.html#using-local-plugins) to do so. Further I have checked other stackoverflow threads for hints ([How to use a local flake8 plugin with a python virtual env?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72364747/how-to-use-a-local-flake8-plugin-with-a-python-virtual-env)), but without success.

I am stuck with the following error message: `flake8.exceptions.FailedToLoadPlugin: Flake8 failed to load plugin "local" due to No package metadata was found for plugin.plugin.`

My repository structure looks like that:

```
.flake8
dev-scripts (from here I run flake8 in a venv created by poetry)
flake8-plugin
  plugin
    __init__.py
    plugin.py (containing the class Plugin)
```

I have tried adding a `setup.py` file to my `flake8-plugin` folder, but it didn't change anything. And since I use the `local-plugins` key in my configuration, I assume that I do not need a `setup.py`.

.flake8:

```
...

[flake8:local-plugins]
# Code ('MR') must match the prefix of the error ids generated by the plugin, otherwise nothing will be reported:
extension =
    MC = plugin.plugin:Plugin
paths =
    ./flake8-plugin/
```

plugin.py contains my Plugin class:

```
...

class Plugin:
    name = __name__
    version: str = importlib.metadata.version(__name__)  

    def __init__(self, tree: ast.AST):
        self._tree = tree

    def run(
        self,
    ) -> typing.Generator[tuple[int, int, str, type[object]]  , None, None]:
        visitor = Visitor()
        visitor.visit(self._tree)

        for line, col, msg in visitor.errors:
            print("error", flush=True)
            yield line, col, msg, type(self)
```

Obviously I am missing something. What could it be?

---

- flake8 version: 5.0.4
- python version: CPython 3.10.6 on Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as of flake8 6.0 the metadata is no longer needed on your plugin class -- you can simply remove both `name` and `version` -- it will be picked up automatically from the plugin installation

note that your error message no longer exists in the latest version of flake8

---

disclaimer: I am the primary flake8 maintainer

Comment: This didn't work for me. I had to install the plugin into the environment to get it work as expected.

Comment: @KayvanShah then you weren't using `local-plugins` or `paths` properly and have a different problem

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

When I remove the `name` and `version` fields of the `Plugin` class, it works. They were artifacts from the tutorial code on that I am building my plugin.

Actually it was sufficient to replace the `version` string by a fixed string, e.g. `"1.0.0"`, but I do not need both fields altogether.